# Check if G5 is a SMP one?

Tags: hardware, cpu, powerpc, g5

How do I check if a G5 PPC mac has 2 CPUs or not?

When booting it up under Linux (Debian 8) only one CPU seems to be detected:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
cpu     : PPC970FX, altivec supported
clock       : 1800.000000MHz
revision    : 3.0 (pvr 003c 0300)

timebase    : 33333333
platform    : PowerMac
model       : PowerMac9,1
machine     : PowerMac9,1
motherboard : PowerMac9,1 MacRISC4 Power Macintosh 
detected as : 337 (PowerMac G5)
pmac flags  : 00000000
L2 cache    : 512K unified
pmac-generation : NewWorld
```

And the kernel should support SMP:

```
uname -a
Linux g5 3.16.0-4-powerpc64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

Does an SMP G5 Macs has 2 heat sinks installed - or is it one big one?

Is there perhaps a OpenFirmware command that lists the CPU details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm not sure about OpenFirmware commands, but your PowerMac G5 only has 1 processor since it's a 9,1.](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g5/specs/powermac_g5_1.8_2.html) I'll edit this later if I can find any. It looks like it's possible in [Single User Mode](http://www.appleexaminer.com/MacsAndOS/Analysis/HowTo/SingleUserMode/SingleUserMode.html), but I'm not sure about via OpenFirmware.

Comment: Single User mode still requires a viable OS X boot - so booting to OS X would get you CPU information as easily as single user.

Comment: @bmike Sadly, yes. I included it anyways since it was the best I could find at the time.

Comment: One should be able to display the device tree in the OpenFirmware environment (cf. e.g. [this guide](http://mac.linux.be/content/guide-open-firmware-apple-bios-0)). And the device tree should be pretty accurate, I presume. This device tree is also accessible under Linux, i.e. under `/proc/device-tree` - and there the `/proc/device-tree/cpus/` directory only contains 1 CPU and `cat /proc/device-tree/model` also yields `PowerMac9,1`.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Sounds like a solution! Add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Considering these two pieces of information

```
processor   : 0
cpu         : PPC970FX
```

It looks like there is only one physical CPU installed and it is a single-core.

I tried finding out if the motherboard supports two physical CPUs but came up empty:

```
motherboard : PowerMac9,1 MacRISC4 Power Macintosh
```

Hopefully some Mac hardware gurus are floating around here that are familiar with that board :)

---

The reason I say the CPU is single-core is because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC_970) states:

> The 970MP is a dual-core derivative of the 970FX